# mod_page speed dependencies issue

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-pagespeed

Before I go any further, mod pagespeed is asking for following dependencies. Is there anything I should check before I go further. Im worred because, I have a apache2.2.22 but its asking for apache2.2-common.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mod-pagespeed-beta:i386:
 mod-pagespeed-beta:i386 depends on apache2.2-common | apache2-api-20120211.
 mod-pagespeed-beta:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4).
 mod-pagespeed-beta:i386 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1-21).
 mod-pagespeed-beta:i386 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.2.1-4).
dpkg: error processing mod-pagespeed-beta:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mod-pagespeed-beta:i386
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably just a package mismatch. You can fix this by running `dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb` then `apt-get install -f` which will automatically install your missing dependencies and get everything to agree.

Comment: ok, i attempted this on a test server, and now apache wont restart. It says"No Apache MPM package installed"

Comment: Try `apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker`

Comment: ok. im now getting Invalid command 'php_value' in all the host config files.

Comment: Is the php module loaded? `a2enmod php5` and use `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5` if it returns an error.

Comment: im going to do a image restore. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you didn't install Apache using apt-get. If so, you cannot use the pre-packaged .deb. Instead you need to build from source. See also: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/faq#missing-dependency and https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_mod_pagespeed_from_source